# Automatically select the default feature in TemplatePicker ARCGIS Javascript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing

I am using this example to implement the editing on my map.

[Editing Without Widget ARCGIS Javascript](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ed_feature_creation/)

The code employs a templatepicker which uses the layers on the map to show the features which can be selected and hence editing can be done on those features.

```
            templatePicker = new TemplatePicker({
                featureLayers: layers,
                rows: "auto",
                columns: 2,
                grouping: true,
                style: "height: auto; overflow: auto;"
            }, "templatePickerDiv");
```

However, you have to select a feature yourself before starting to edit it. After selection, the selected feature is fetched as

```
selectedTemplate = templatePicker.getSelected();
```

This **selectedTemplate** is then selected to put the points on the map.

```
selectedTemplate.featureLayer.applyEdits([newGraphic], null, null);
```

**The problem is**, I want to select the default or first feature in the templatePicker automatically as it loads. I tried finding if TemplatePicker has any method to select any feature but I couldnt. Is there any way that I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a programmatic hook into selecting a template immediately.  just wire up logic to invoke the appropriate draw tool and pass edits to your hardcoded featureLayer of interest on `draw-end` immediately upon map load.

afterward, you can still listen for `selection-change` on TemplatePicker and direct the edits somewhere else.

Comment: Oh, it is that simple. I am very new to ARCGIS, in fact I started just a couple of weeks ago. Thanks for the help. I was able to resolve the issue with 

featureLayer.applyEdits([newGraphic], null, null);

where featureLayer is the layer variable which has already been added to the map

Comment: no problem @Taha Rehman Siddiqui.  i'm happy to help.